Jitpack.io does not work with Java 17 Temurin
    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
            vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTIUM
        }
    }

Jitpack.io only works if I comment vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTIUM out. How can I use Jitpack with that line? In the Gradle docs there's something with providers that I don't understand (for Jitpack). Who has a solution?
Gradle 8.4, https://github.com/SoltauFintel/amalia
